# How to increase size of this partition?

Tags: partitioning, disk

[image]

(SS from Ubuntu 18.04, gparted.)

I had Windows, Ubuntu and Mint installed. Ubuntu had 200 GBs and Mint had 100 GBs. I wanted to reverse it, so while I was on Mint, I resized the partition which contains Ubuntu(`sda8`) and lowered it to 112GBs, now I have 88GBs of unallocated space.

Then I have passed to ubuntu in order to enlarge the partition of Mint, which is `sda9`. However, I cannot do it. I tried to somehow move `sda8` to the rightmost so that `sda9` and `unallocated` spaces will be side-to-side, however I could not achieve it.

So, how can I do it?

Comment: I think the problem is you moved `sda8` (ubuntu) to the left. You should have moved it to the right in order to have unallocated between`sda9` and `sda8`. Do that from mint, then switch to Ubuntu to grow mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to boot into Mint, so that `/dev/sda 8` (ubuntu) ist not mounted. Then it will be easier to move that partition.

After that it should be possible to enlarge `/dev/sda9` (mint). You can even increase directly in Mint itself. But if you want to, you can go back in Ubuntu and increase the partition there.

Comment: I'll be there in few minutes

Comment: It said moving starting point of a partition may cause system not to boot, bla bla... I did not have any crucial things on ubuntu, so I accepted and now it is copying the files.

Comment: yep, it worked!

Comment: Could you increase the size in Mint itself or have you had to reboot into Ubuntu for that?

Comment: I did not have to change to ubuntu again, it turned out that you can directly increase size of the partition which your OS is installed on.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my answer to be shorter and more accurate now with your given knowledge.